# how can i use android ListView to display fields in an object?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to construct a `ListActivity` that uses a listview to display a list of friends and their associated status (ie single, in a relationship).

So far, I have an ArrayAdapter set like so:

```
Friend[] friendList = new Friend[] {
    new Friend("john doe", "single"), 
    new Friend("jane doe", "married")
};

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this, R.layout.portal_listview, friendList));
```

I would like each item in the listview to display as such:

1name: john doe 
status: single

2name: jane doe
status: married

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create you own CustomArrayAdapter which extends `ArrayAdapter` and overwrite the `View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method

I could be something like this

```
public class FriendAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend>{
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<Friend> friends;

    public FriendAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Friend> friends) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(your_list_item_resource, null);
        }
        Friend friend = friends.get(position);
        view.setId(position);
        if (friend != null){
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
            name.setText(friend.getName());
            TextView status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendStatus);
            status.setText(friend.getStatus());
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml row file, you can add a composite object, like a LinearLayout
and inside that you could include more than one textview, or a combination etc.

I guess the linearlayout would be unnecessary if the individual items within the list are displayed vertically, but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getView` in the `ArrayAdapter` class.  In that method, inflate your `R.layout.portal_listview` instance and fill it with whatever you want.

That xml layout should be some layout form that includes a `TextView` for the two things you want to display.

Easiest would be a linear layout, set to **vertical orientation**, with 2 TextViews in it, stacked.